# Incorrect number of bindings supplied for CSV Sqlite Python script

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, insert

I'm try to insert values into my sqlite table using a python script.

It was working perfectly until I tried to add another column called 'information' - it then threw the following error:

```
You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings
```

So I added:

```
conn.text_factory = str
```

Then I got this error:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 7, and there are 3 supplied.
```

I think the problem is that this new 'information' column contains a few lines of text so I may be specifying it incorrectly as 'text'. My python script code:

```
import sqlite3;
from datetime import datetime, date;
import time
conn = sqlite3.connect('mynewtable.sqlite3')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists mynewtable')
c.execute('create table mynewtable(id integer primary key autoincrement, rank integer, placename text, information text, nooftimes integer, visit text, fav integer, year integer)')

def mysplit (string):
quote = False
retval = []
current = ""
for char in string:
    if char == '"':
        quote = not quote
    elif char == ',' and not quote:
        retval.append(current)
        current = ""
    else:
        current += char
retval.append(current)
return retval

# Read lines from file, skipping first line
data = open("mynewtable.csv", "r").readlines()[1:]
for entry in data:
# Parse values
vals = mysplit(entry.strip())

# Insert the row!
print "Inserting %s..." % (vals[0])
sql = "insert into mynewtable values(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
c.execute(sql, vals)

# Done!
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you post the block of code instead of that one line that only creates the table?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I've added the full script now. I should have posted it all initially, sorry and thanks!

Comment: See the 2nd edit in my answer for a re-worked version of you program that uses the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to re-invent the wheel a bit here :)

Try using python's csv module; I've used it extensively and it works very well:
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

It works perfectly well with properly formed csv files that have multi-line texts.

**EDIT:**

For example, you can use the csv rows (which are lists) directly in your execute function:

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(open('allnamesallyearsn.csv')):
    c.execute(sql, row)
```

**2nd EDIT:**

As per my last comment, here is the code you posted making use of the csv module:

```
import sqlite3, csv, time
from datetime import datetime, date

conn = sqlite3.connect('mynewtable.sqlite3')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists mynewtable')
c.execute('create table mynewtable('
          'id integer primary key autoincrement, '
          'rank integer, '
          'placename text, '
          'information text, '
          'nooftimes integer, '
          'visit text, '
          'fav integer, '
          'year integer)')

sql_insert = "insert into mynewtable values(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('mynewtable.csv', 'rb'))
csv_reader.next() # skip headers
for csv_row in csv_reader:
    print "Inserting %s..." % (csv_row)
    c.execute(sql_insert, csv_row)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Haha thanks! I do tend to try and re-invent the wheel a lot.. That document is great but I'm not sure how to implement it, will the output of that module give me an sqlite db? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes I meant this to be purely an example on how the csv module provides you with each record properly parsed and so you don't have to bother with interpreting the CSV file directly yourself. I'll edit my post with your program (though I don't guarantee that it'll compile, even less work since I'll just be trying to put my example in your context a little more).

Comment: Hi thanks very much! Will get this working, really appreciate it!